# Republishing a content type will not take effect

Tags: 2013, content-type, site-collection, configuration, content-type-hub

I have a site collection which act as a content type hub. i created a new CT and i publish it. then i add a new column inside the CT and i republish the CT.

but currently when other site collections consumes the CT the new column will not appear? although i run the two timer job :-

```
Content Type Hub    
Content Type Subscriber
```

so can anyone adivce. i also try to Un-publishing then publish the CT, but still the new column is not being shown in the consumers site collections ?

Comment: do you see any content syndication errors in the consuming sites?
<site>/_layouts/15/contenttypesyndicationhubs.aspx then in the Content type publishing error log:
<site>/Lists/ContentTypeSyncLog

Comment: @JasonJones where exactly i can check for these errors ?

Comment: If you go to one of the sites that is part of the content type syndication and site (collection) settings you will see an option for "Content Type Publishing" - the errors link is on that page.